# How to get the date value from a log file which contains the timestamp

Tags: shell

Below is the log file of one of my batch job and I am trying to get the date value alone from the timestamp in shell

```
Extract.120420180130.log
```

Expected output : 12042018

Comment: You are "trying to" - what did you try?

Comment: cut -f2 -d. here_comes_the_log_file | cut -c-8

Comment: That suggestion works on the assumption that you want 8 characters after the first `.`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, tr -dc to keep only numeric chars, then get first 8 chars with cut :

```
fileName=Extract.120420180130.log
date=$(echo $fileName | tr -dc '0-9' |cut -c1-8)
echo $date
12042018
```